# Add an easy way to copy deeplink to answers

Tags: feature-request

Consider the situation where I want to link directly to a specific answer. There is no easy way to do so, unless we qualify manual URL manipulation as 'easy'.

Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria) question for example. I'm particularly interested in one answer, in this case the accepted (and thus top listed) answer. In fact, I like the answer so much, I'd like to refer to in comments in my code.
I can only link to the question directly by copying  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria` from the address bar, but there's no way (afaik) to get an answer.

I can ofcourse add `#answer-3754470` manually, but well, that's just, manually.

**tl;dr**:
Can we get a small link-icon near each answer so I can deeplink faster?

Answer (score 2):

Each answer already has a 'Share' button that allows this:

[image]

Comment: Well I kinda missed that :D